# MongoDB PHP Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm stuck with this strange problem.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// connect to mongodb
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(array("ping" => 1));
$result = $manager->executeCommand("test", $command);

var_dump($result, $result->toArray());
?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on 'localhost:27017'] in /var/www/html/mongo.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mongo.php(11): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeCommand('test', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Command)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mongo.php on line 11
```

Why it is strange? Well, I already tried searching around the internet about this problem, people always say the same thing:

1. The MongoDB server is offline
2. The MongoDB server data is corrupted

Well...

It isn't offline, my Java applications (and "mongo") can connect to the MongoDB server just fine and can interact with the database without throwing the ConnectionTimeoutException.

```
try {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" );
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It isn't corrupted, because if it was corrupted, I won't be able to connect it via Java (right?)

I already tried connecting to 127.0.0.1 and localhost, same issue.

I already tried restarting httpd and mongod, same issue.

I already tried binding the MongoDB server to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, same issue.

Yes, MongoDB drivers are installed, they are active in PHP Info.

MongoDB PHP version: 1.2.1

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10 (now updated to 3.4.0)

PHP version: 7.0.13

Comment: I'm passing by this error too, it's driving me crazy already.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I think I should come back to say how I fixed the issue (thanks @jmikola!)

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/484

You need to use

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

to fix the issue.

Comment: this is not works on mac, isn't a solution, still a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue:

```
Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (serverSelectionTryOnce set)
```

I searched a lot but did not get any solution..
using macOs catalina , php 7.2

after I opened terminal and run command

```
mongod --dbpath Users/username/data/db
```

--dbpath is your /data/db path

and my code is working properly..