# MongoDb php7 on linux return "no suitable servers found" when try to execute query

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

i have a problem with mongodb php driver on php7, it was fine when i use for php 5.6, and dont need to call the things like mongodb\driver\manager... but now im stuck here, i dont know whats wrong.

```
<?php  

$host = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://username:password@hostname:port/database");

$start = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2018-08-01'.' 00:00:00'));
$end = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2018-08-31'.' 23:59:59'));

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(array('created' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
$cursor = $host->executeQuery('database.transactions', $query);

var_dump($cursor);exit;   

?>
```

its return

> Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No
>   suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection
>   refused calling ismaster on 'hostname:port']
>
> MongoDB\Driver\Manager-executeQuery('database.transactions...',Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query))

hostname and port is just example. i already try to connect with real host and port, it works fine when use mongod console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057321/mongodb-php-uncaught-mongodb-driver-exception-connectiontimeoutexception-no-sui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB PHP Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057321/mongodb-php-uncaught-mongodb-driver-exception-connectiontimeoutexception-no-sui)

Comment: i have tried that solution, but still doesnt work